# How do I clear application cache python?

Tags: python, ios, debugging, kivy

I am currently trying to find a solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68671623/kivy-audiostream-issue-recording-audio-after-outputting-audio) I posted earlier today and I have noticed that, if I quit and restart the app after outputting audio through the speakers, I can then successfully record audio again (i.e. my problem goes away). **So, I was wondering if anyone knew what happens 'under the hood' when an iOS python/kivy app is restarted?** If so, how could I replicate these behaviours within my code during run-time?

Comment: You should edit your original question to add detail or seek clarification. Your problem is probably that out aren't releasing a resource or re-configuring something in the audio system correctly. Asking what happens when an app is restarted won't help you, since your entire app environment is reset to initial conditions. You need to specifically look at what those initial conditions are for audio and determine what you aren't resetting and this is what you are already asking in your initial question.

Comment: You probably need to work out which native audio frameworks the python code is using and read the docs for that to work out how the python module maps to the audio session mode.

Comment: Hi @Paulw11 thanks for your advice; I will edit the question now. Do you have any ideas as to what these audio configurations would be/how to go about determining them?

Comment: @Paulw11 Just seen your response; thanks so much! Will do that.